# In MS Word, when pasting contents containing numbered lists, how can I prevent these lists automatically merged?

Tags: microsoft-word

For example, there is a table in my doc shown as:

[image: Table]

In *Table1*, there are 3 numbered lists. When I choose the whole table, copy it, and paste it, I get:

[image: Copied and pasted table]

In the new table, let's say *Table1a*, there are 3 numbered lists, each of which is merged with lists in *Table1*. Lists in *Table1a* are numbered continuously after lists in *Table1*.

**My question is**: How can I prevent lists merged when pasting. Thus, when pasting there is no relation between lists in *Table1a* and *Table1*, and I can get:

[image: Desired table]

Comment: Typically you need to make a line break (insert line feed) to end a Style and start another Style (or the same one).  I usually put in several line feeds temporarily to insert a section of text with paste.

Comment: @John I have tried both Enter and Shift+Enter, leaving empty line and empty row, before and after the list. None works. Thanks for the suggestion anyway.

Comment: @John 2 In Word, there is a huge difference between a paragraph break (Enter) and a line break (Shift+Enter). The second continues the paragraph, the first starts a new paragraph.

Comment: To do this simply, you need to convert the text from automatic numbering to plain text. If this were not tables, I would say simply paste as plain text. As it is, I think a macro is needed. Cross-posted at https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/in-ms-word-when-pasting-contents-containing/c823061b-352d-4ece-b30a-05c8c5afb851?. For cross-posting etiquette, please read: A Message to Forum Cross-Posters https://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multilevel list solves my problem. Here is how it works.

1. Create a new multilevel list. For level 1, make numbering empty. For level 2, use 1, 2, 3, ... as numbering.
2. In Table1 in my first pic, set Text1, Text2, Text3 formatted in multilevel list created in step 1.
3. Set all cells from Text1-1 to Text3-3 formatted in multilevel list created in step 1. Make them be level 2.
4. Now feel free to copy and paste the table. The tables and lists will be the same as shown in my third pic. Since all the contents are still managed by numbered lists, inserting or deleting a row does not require any manual modification on numbers. When cells of several rows, left column are merged, cells of the same rows, right column are automatically treated as a level 2 list, numbered in 1, 2, 3, ... When copying and pasting, left columns of tables are merged into one multilevel list (level 1), right columns remain seperate level 2 lists.

I also post the question on MS forum, and get the suggestion of multilevel list there. Visit https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/in-ms-word-when-pasting-contents-containing/c823061b-352d-4ece-b30a-05c8c5afb851 if you are interested.